# Looping in Powershell and Splitting Out Results to separate Files

Tags: html, powershell, loops, scripting

I don't script that offered, so I keep forgetting how to tackle some things.. I'm running the below piece of script and writing the output to a file which I convert to HTML for emailing at a later date.. The code works & generates a complete file of all users.. Which is great !! But what I want, is to  separate the file for each user, so that I can email them the results individually.

There is some code prior to this which creates the file and adds all the necessary parameters for the HTML content. Header, Border etc...

```
ForEach ($User in $Members) {     
    $Session = Get-Whiteboard -UserId $User.ObjectId

    If ($Session.Count -gt 0) {      

        ForEach ($s in $Session) {        

            $TimeDiff = New-TimeSpan $s.createdTime $Limit                         

            If ($TimeDiff.Days -gt 1)  {
                $UserName = $User.DisplayName
                $SessionID = $s.id
                $SessionCreationDate = $s.createdTime
                $Diff = $TimeDiff.Days            

                Add-Content $report "<tr>"
                Add-Content $report "<td>$UserName</td>"
                Add-Content $report "<td>$SessionID</td>"
                Add-Content $report "<td>$SessionCreationDate</td>"
                Add-Content $report "<td>$Diff</td>"
                Add-Content $report "<tr>"
            }
        }
    
    } Else { 
        #Do Something
    }
}
```

Attached is the output of the script, so how do I split this out.. Any ideas would be apprenticed.

Output is not attaching..... but it's something like this

```
User1
User1
User1
User2
User2
User3
User4
```

Comment: Where is `$report` defined?

Comment: $report is defined higher up in the script, which I've not included.$Report is just the txt file which is created to build the contents. I'm pipping HTML parameters using Add-Content to $Report.

Comment: So, in other words, you already know exactly what to change in order to write your HTML to a different file? :)

Comment: Okay, your comment has got me thinking, need to put the whole lot in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it... Just had to move the code inside the loop and make a few tweaks.. All is good